# Is there any known encrypting ransomware that attacks Macs?

Tags: malware, virus, macos, ransomware

Just about every article I read about Cryptowall, Cryptolocker, and its ilk seems to assume that the reader is running some flavor of Windows.

When I Google "ransomware OSX", I get a long list of articles about the [FBI Javascript "ransomware"](https://blog.malwarebytes.org/fraud-scam/2013/07/fbi-ransomware-now-targeting-apples-mac-os-x-users/).  However, this is not really ransomware in the same sense as Cryptowall and Cryptolocker, as it does not actually penetrate outside of the browser, and does not encrypt your files.  I would consider this to be the [milk snake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milk_snake#Description) of the ransomware world.

So is there any **true** encrypting ransomware that affects Macs?

Comment: Well, the first "real" version has surfaced not too long ago now through infected Transmission downloads. They called it KeRanger: http://researchcenter.paloaltonetworks.com/2016/03/new-os-x-ransomware-keranger-infected-transmission-bittorrent-client-installer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would consider this to be the milk snake of the ransomware world.

In that you are right, FBI *ransomware*  is rather a crafted malicious JS code that is more annoying and scaring than penetrating the operating system, and as you can read on the [TheSafeMac](http://www.thesafemac.com/fbi-ransomware-virus-rampant/):

> …there is no indication that this is actually Mac malware of any kind.
>   It’s simply an obnoxious browser pop-up, displayed via JavaScript, in
>   an attempt to fool people into paying.

Actually, by the beginning of this year, [CISCO announced via its blogs](http://blogs.cisco.com/security/talos/cryptowall-2) that a new version of Cryptowall(2.0) has appeared. It uses Tor  It is even able to  run  both on 64-bits and 32-bits processors. It affects all versions of Microsoft Windows but [also](http://securityaffairs.co/wordpress/31993/cyber-crime/cryptowall-ransomware-2-0.html) the [newer versions of Mac OS X](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2867132/cryptowall-ransomware-variant-has-new-defenses.html):

> It is coded to run on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems, which increases
>   its chances of running on whatever computer it infects, Carter said.
>   **Newer versions of Mac OS X** and Windows are 64-bit operating systems.

Comment: So, have there been any confirmed cases of Cryptowall infecting a 64-bit version of OSX?

Comment: @alexw Good question. Actually, I mentioned 2 links stating that it affects newer versions of Mac OS x, I can add you [this](http://it.okstate.edu/advisories/cryptowall.php) and many others, but I did not hear yet for a successful infection on this OS, **as well as** I did not hear that this new version of Cryptowall infected users of Microsoft Windows

Comment: @Begueradj – Technically the article states that the new version can run on both 32-bit and 64 bit and then goes on to say that the latest version of Mac OS X is a 64-bit operating system. The language seems to be written in a way that a reader would infer then that this will affect Macs as well but I think that it makes things clear as mud.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, now there is a confirmed and well documented case of ransomware specifically targeting Mac OS X. It was named "KeRanger" and was distributed through a breach of the Transmission Bittorrent Client website.

http://researchcenter.paloaltonetworks.com/2016/03/new-os-x-ransomware-keranger-infected-transmission-bittorrent-client-installer/

Some basic OS X security features (Gatekeeper) had been circumvented by using a valid developer certificate. Apple has since revoked that certificate and updated it's XProtect signature list, but obviously this happened after the malware had already done damage.